# How do I apply Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem here?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> Find the radius of convergence of the power series
> $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2} $$

I understand how to use the Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem for power series with $x^n$ but am unsure what to do when in this context, ant help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Realise this hasn't submitted exactly how i wanted it to, new to this so am still learning, the link should go to the question i am asking.

Comment: Hint : you can write your series as $\sum a_n x^n$ where $(a_n)$ has lots of zeros and some ones here and there

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$ with $$a_k=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }\exists n\in\Bbb N,\, k=n^2\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Therefore $\lvert a_k\rvert^{1/k}=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }\exists n\in\Bbb N,\, k=n^2\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ (for $k>0$). Therefore $\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty}\lvert a_k\rvert^{1/k}=1$ and the radius of convergence is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Written as a standard series, it is $\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n X^n,\:$ where
$\;\begin{cases}
a_n=1 &\text{if $n$ is a square},\\
a_n=0&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$

Can  you compute $\limsup a_n^{1/n}$?